# C++ pointers or memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

My code seems like it should be working given the algorithm, but I'm new to C++ and it seems that these pointers are overwriting themselves when I call insert multiple times. For example, if I call insert with values 1, 3, 5, then the root will be 1 (as expected), but 3 will be overwritten and the right child of the root will have value 5 instead of 3.

```
virtual bool insert(const Data& item) {
if(root == NULL){
  BSTNode<Data> newNode (item);
  root = &newNode;
  isize++;
  return true;
}
BSTNode<Data>* nextNode = root;
BSTNode<Data>* prevNode = NULL;
bool isLeft;
while(nextNode!=NULL) {
  if (item < nextNode->data) {
    prevNode = nextNode;
    nextNode = nextNode->left;
    //std::cout << prevNode->data;
    isLeft = true;
  }
  else {
    prevNode = nextNode;
    nextNode = nextNode->right;
    //std::cout << prevNode->data;
    isLeft = false;
  }
}
BSTNode<Data> createNode (item);
createNode.parent = prevNode;
if (isLeft) prevNode->left = &createNode;
else prevNode->right = &createNode;
isize++;
return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're new to C++, why do you work with pointers? It's a complex thing, it's best to avoid it until you're firm with the rest. It's also barely necessary to deal with them directly. Embrace the abstraction (provided by the standard library and soon your own classes)!

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid pointer due to pointing to a local object which is going to destroy:

```
BSTNode<Data> newNode (item);
root = &newNode;
```

Object `newNode` is a local object within method `insert` after returning from this method (it goes out of scope), pointer `root` will point to a destroyed object. 
A naive possibility to solve the problem is allocating `newNode` in heap by `new`:

```
root = new BSTNode<Data>(item);
```

but you must `delete` it somewhere, and also same issue for `createNode`.

---

As recommended by many, you should use smart-points such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `root` is a member variable, you need to allocate it on the heap and not on the stack:

```
if(root == NULL){
  root = new BSTNode<Data>(item);
  isize++;
  return true;
}
```

Otherwise the node is destroyed once it goes out of scope at the closing brace of the `if` body. The same goes for

```
if (isLeft) prevNode->left = new BSTNode<Data>(item);
else prevNode->right = new BSTNode<Data>(item);
```

I haven't checked your actual insertion logic though. You should should post the entire code, there is too little here to check it. Is it a binary tree?

Edit: Don't forget to delete the nodes if you create them on the heap, as per M M's answer.